# Qual o problema da frase "muito, muito meu amor você”?

Tags: gramática

Em uma conversa rotineira, me deparei com a frase:

> — Muito, muito meu amor você

Mas achei estranha a colocação das palavras. O que está estranho, e por quê?

Comment: Me parece uma frase com o verbo omitido e ordem diferente da usual: "Você é meu amor." -> "Meu amor você é." -> Meu amor, você."

Comment: Eu imaginei a frase no seguinte contexto: *"Você me ama?"* — perguntou ela. *"— Muito, muito, meu amor. Você…"* — Respondeu-a.

Comment: Você do contexto exato dessa frase, David?

Comment: Fora de contexto,  parece uma frase dita por falante não-nativo.

Comment: Eu não entendo porque um nativo falante faz perguntas sobre frases com características típicas de conversa. As pessoas quando falam, falam de muitos jeitos que não se podem sempre explicar. Saem coisas encurtadas. Acho também que você deveria dar um palpite e tentar dizer algo.

Comment: Você quer viajar comigo? Resposta: Muito, muito meu amor. E você? Mas a suposta frase não é uma frase. É coisa bagunçada de pessoas escrevendo na internet ou em mensagens de texto....

Answer (score 2):

Eu vejo a frase assim:

> És muito, és muito o meu amor, tu.

É uma repetição de "és o *MEU* amor" sem pronomes, nem artigos, e em especial sem o verbo.

Acho que a pergunta é boa, francamente não tenho as regras gramaticais da sintax decoradas para analisar a frase em detalhe com a terminologia própria.

Mas acho que a frase é válida, no sentido literário. Recorda-me os romances do final do séc XIX mas já com uma construção de frase mais moderna que tenta retratar personagens populares sem florear o discurso.

Para quem tiver dúvidas, se lerem a [Crónica do Condestável](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%B3nica_do_Condest%C3%A1vel) muitas vezes vemos frases assim, sem formalismos, de expressão directa, puro uso da língua Portuguesa sem olhar a detalhes. O que tem um certo encanto, reconheço.

Answer (score 1):

Tá muito esquisito. 
No entanto, não tenho conhecimento suficiente da literatura pra afirmar com certeza que não há esse estilo. 
Dentro da minha ilimitada ignorância não é um estilo conhecido da língua portuguesa
Talvez, num diálogo, se fosse  a resposta de um interlocutor:
--- Muito muito, meu amor, você.

Nota. Nesse sentido o estilo foi usar o advérbio "muito" como advérbio de intensidade do próprio: "muito"

Ao invés de "muito mesmo" ou "muitíssimo"

Answer (score 1):

Semántica e sintácticamente essa frase não existe. Provavelmente a pessoa "comeu" alguma palavra na hora de digitar.

Answer (score 0):

Usando exatamente essa pontuação e sem contexto arrodeando, o estranhamento vem por conta de, literalmente, faltar informação. 
É muito o que? Seu amor pela pessoa? A resposta à pergunta anterior? Muito é um advérbio de intensidade, então precisa ser acompanhado necessariamente de um verbo condutor!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine a situation where this sentence would make sense, but it's impossible to say if it's the same meaning from where you heard it without knowing the context.

Informally, in portuguese you can say to someone "Isto é muito você", meaning "this is a lot like you" or "that kind of thing is so characteristic of you".

For example: In a conversation, the husband says "Eu esperei meu tio ir embora para não ter que conversar" (I waited for my uncle to leave so I would not need to talk). And the wife answers "Meu amor, isto é muito você", meaning "my dear, this is very characteristic of you".

Could that be the case?

Comment: Welcome Gaspar! Your answer is nice, probably useful to the asker, but it was asked in Portuguese and we tend to answer in the same language, as we can't be sure if he'll understand your very good answer. Are you able to translate it to Portuguese, please?

Comment: Adorei a explicação dada en inglês.